# Why is a textbox's focused property not true when it is in focus?

Tags: c#, winforms

Although I've made sure that one of these text boxes are indeed in focus, the Focused property is false for each one. Why?

```
private TextBox GetTextboxInFocus()
    {
        if (txtFeet.Focused)
        {
            return txtFeet;
        }
        if (txtInches.Focused)
        {
            return txtInches;
        }
        if (txtSixteenths.Focused)
        {
            return txtSixteenths;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: [ActiveControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Are you sure that one of the elements still has the focus when your function is reached? You could listen to GotFocus and LostFocus and write to console to be sure...

Comment: Debug your code and see what happens. Explain how you guarantee that one of those `TextBoxes` is focused and how do you invoke `GetTextboxInFocus()`?

Comment: Focused means that the cursor is in the textbox.  Clicking anything else to invoke that code, ie button will potentially lose the focus on the textbox.  How are you invoking?

Comment: @Michael How would you use textbox in console application? :) Just kidding... You have valid point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be with you calling/invoking ...

I have made a sample code for you understanding ...

```
    private void CheckFocusAndShowResults(string throughControl)
    {
        var result = GetTextboxInFocus();

        if (result == null)
        {
            label1.Text = "No textbox is focused.";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = string.Format("textbox {0} is focused and {1} is called.", result.Name, throughControl);
        }
    }
```

[image]

When try to invoke through button ... No textbox gets focused.

[image]

Then I added two events for textbox to verify the focus ...

```
    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckFocusAndShowResults("Texbox Click Event");
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckFocusAndShowResults("Texbox Leave Event");
    }
```

When clicking on textbox1, first event is fired and textbox1 gets focused (see label)

[image]

When leaving the textbox1, second event is fired and textbox1 gets focused meanwhile evaluating the condition ... although currently focus was on textbox2 (highlighted by blue outline).

So you can call either on Click or Leave events as I shown.

[image]